# Extern property

Tags: c#, properties, interpreter

I am creating an interpreter from IL (A compiled C#\VB code) to C. I tried to create [extern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5.aspx) property when I interpret it I'll set my own code.

For an example:

```
struct String {
    public extern override ValueType Clone( ); //Works but with some warnings.
    public char this[ int index ] {
        extern get;
        //'System.String.this[int].get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
        //The modifier 'extern' is not valid for this item
        extern set; //Didn't work either.
    }
}
```

How I can make getters and setters without body? (BTW I can't mark it as [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) too without getting errors.)

I know this question isn't useful. But very to me.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do. Please clarify. As far as I know, there's no real-world thing called an "extern property". So what do you _want_ that to mean?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I know there isn't use for it. But I want the property to be exists in the code ,but when I convert it from IL to C I want to put my own C code.

Comment: I didn't say there was no use for it. I asked you to tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JohnSaunders `I tried to create extern property when I interpret it I'll set my own code.`. My interpreter has table of strings and when it sees the extern modifier at something ,it puts string from the table.

Comment: have you tried making it static? 
The extern modifier is used to declare a method that is implemented externally. A common use of the extern modifier is with the DllImport attribute when using Interop services to call into unmanaged code; in this case, the method must also be declared as static, as shown in the following example:
[DllImport("avifil32.dll")]
private static extern void AVIFileInit();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @hagensoft I am putting my unmanaged code when my interpreter interpret it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to suggest your interpretator to use alternative implemetation (instead of IL use your custom code). Most CLR friendly way would be to create attribute that your interpreter will read and correspondingly use some of your own code, sort of reverse PInvoke.

```
struct MyString { 
[WhenRunningInInterpretator(implementationFunction="function42")]
public char this[ int index ] { 
    get {...}  set {....};    } 
}
```

Comment: I alright answered my question but I can't answer it because I don't have enough rep.. My answer is really similar to yours. Mine is to create class that inherits exception and throw it. When the interpreter'll see this it'll put code and the C# compiler'll not bother me about the return value. Thanks anyway :).

Comment: Found another something I can make it `public extern char this[ int index ] { get; set; }` to make it extern. How retard of me XD.